# SQL joining data from four tables with multiple where

Tags: sql

Hi I have the following sql statement which used to work fine linking four tables. The tables are Person (c, e), Relation (d), PersonFamily(b), Family(a). 
I added the condition WHERE d.Relationship LIKE '%Father' as I want to filter that particular relationship so it only retrieves data for (c) if the relationship is a father, stepfather,grandfather etc. As soon as I added this, it failed - I haven't managed to find examples with multiple where conditions in as I need to need to add a further one for mother but I want it to appear in the same row under f.Title,f.Forename,f.Surname.

I think if I can understand how to do a multiple where in sql, I might be able to retrieve the mother data out as well

```
SELECT a.pk_FamilyID, a.Salutation, e.Title, e.Forename, e.Surname, c.Title, c.Forename, c.Surname
FROM Family a
INNER JOIN PersonFamily b ON a.pk_FamilyID = b.fk_FamilyID
INNER JOIN Person c ON b.fk_PersonID = c.pk_PersonID
INNER JOIN Relation d ON c.pk_PersonID = d.fk_RelatedPersonID
WHERE d.Relationship LIKE '%Father'
INNER JOIN Person e ON d.fk_PersonID = e.pk_PersonID
WHERE e.pk_PersonID IN('" & Substitute ( ListOfPersonUUID ; ¶ ; "','" ) & "')
ORDER BY e.SurnameForename ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the multiple conditions in where using the `AND/OR` operator whichever suitable for your requirements. In this condition you might need to use the `AND` operator. I am assuming you want to get result if relation is in the `%Father` `OR` `%Mother` that's why added the `(d.Relationship LIKE '%Father' OR d.Relationship LIKE '%Mother')` condition in where part.

```
SELECT a.pk_FamilyID, a.Salutation, e.Title, e.Forename, e.Surname, c.Title, c.Forename, c.Surname
FROM Family a
INNER JOIN PersonFamily b ON a.pk_FamilyID = b.fk_FamilyID
INNER JOIN Person c ON b.fk_PersonID = c.pk_PersonID
INNER JOIN Relation d ON c.pk_PersonID = d.fk_RelatedPersonID
INNER JOIN Person e ON d.fk_PersonID = e.pk_PersonID
WHERE (d.Relationship LIKE '%Father' OR d.Relationship LIKE '%Mother')
AND e.pk_PersonID IN('" & Substitute ( ListOfPersonUUID ; ¶ ; "','" ) & "')
ORDER BY e.SurnameForename ASC
```

Comment: And you can also add multiple conditions in "JOIN ... ON"

Comment: Thanks, I understand now why I couldn't find multiple where. Your code sample is still producing a null - but I think I understand the syntax I need to use to put two where conditions in

Comment: @Rubik Yes I can it will not make any change in the `Inner Join` but in case of  other join that will make difference.And that will confuse the OP. As OP is new to sql I just wanted to  make it clear to the OP how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple `WHERE` clauses on the same dataset. Conditions need to be either separated by logical operators like `AND`, `OR` or you need to put the `WHERE` inside the datasets.

You can have this:

```
SELECT a.pk_FamilyID, a.Salutation, e.Title, e.Forename, e.Surname, c.Title, c.Forename, c.Surname
FROM Family a
INNER JOIN PersonFamily b ON a.pk_FamilyID = b.fk_FamilyID
INNER JOIN Person c ON b.fk_PersonID = c.pk_PersonID
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Relation d WHERE Relationship LIKE '%Father')ON c.pk_PersonID = d.fk_RelatedPersonID
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Person WHERE pk_PersonID IN('" & Substitute ( ListOfPersonUUID ; ¶ ; "','" ) & "'))e ON d.fk_PersonID = e.pk_PersonID
ORDER BY e.SurnameForename
```